# What is a Function that Creates Functions Called?

Tags: naming, functions

Let's say I have the following function (in JavaScript, for sake of example):

```
function foo() {
  var bar = function () {return 'lol';}
  return bar;
}
```

This function returns other functions. I had the misconception that this was called a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)), but on reading around, that's something different entirely. Googling this question didn't give me anything useful.

So, what do I call a function that creates functions?

Comment: "Higher order function"

Comment: _A higher order function is a function that takes a function as an argument, or returns a function_

Comment: I call them funky funcs.

Comment: I think Fabio is right, but he forgot to add the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) where he cited from.

Comment: "Function", or the exact type `() -> () -> String` (in the case of that example)

Comment: I think RibaldEddie is probably right, but the more common term is "Higher order function", as Fabio stated.

Comment: Higher Order Function usually takes a function as an argument, as in the Wikipedia examples.  OP's code, as given, doesn't.  In the case where the function returned is a Promise, I've seen these called Promise Factories:  https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: Another "source": [Higher-order functions](https://youtu.be/BMUiFMZr7vk)

Comment: @user949300 Depends, in Haskell [_all_](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) functions with more than one argument are (or rather, can be used as) higher-order functions.

Comment: how about a "wrapper"?